# What is the best way to include comments in my ASP.NET MVC 3 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms

In Wordpress, I can enable wp_comments to show the commenting system.

I want to write code so that whenever I write comments in HTML markup, it calls my comments written codes.

How can I achieve this in ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET web forms?

Comment: Not sure what you really want here. Wordpress is a blog/cms engine; ASP.NET is a web framework. You can't really compare them. It'd be like comparing a whole car to a car engine.

Comment: I would say it's rather like comparing chisel and a hammer to a wooden chair :)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to add comments to your ASP.NET MVC 3 web project.

**1. Develop a comments section within your application**

If you wish to create bespoke commenting functionality for your site, [this article](http://dashingquill.web.officelive.com/blogs/Create_Comments_in_Asp_Net_MVC_Website.aspx) gives you a clear walk-through on how you can achieve this.

**2. Integrate third party comment service into your website**

Alternatively, you could use a third party service like DISQUS and integrate it into your app. [Here's a link](http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/Integrate-DISQUS-For-Comment-Management-In-MVC.aspx) outlining how to do this.

There's no 'out of the box' commenting system for ASP.NET. Also, you can't really compare the ASP.NET MVC Framework with Wordpress as they are completely different.

***Since you have specific functionality (outputting HTML markup), I'd recommend option #1.***

Comment: +1 for *comparing apples to screws*... Because that's what it is. Screws are building blocks of something, apples are just treats you can eat out of the box.

Comment: Just an FYI, the link for your first item is broken (the site has been removed).